# Excelwriter freeze position of a sheet itself (not at row or column level)?

Tags: python, pandas.excelwriter

I'm using `excelwriter` engine. My excel file has more than 50 sheets/tabs with the first being a 'summary' sheet (which has internal links for other 50 tabs). I'm looking for a freeze option at the sheet level itself, so that summary sheet's position would always be frozen and horizontal scrolling can be avoided in order to move to first sheet.

I have tried `freeze_panes` but it can be used at rows and columns level inside a sheet. similar stuff with `set_scrollarea` or `set_sheet_view` etc.

Comment: Since its not a default functionality in excel, the only way I found to do anything similar is [through VBA](https://www.extendoffice.com/documents/excel/2695-excel-lock-freeze-worksheet-tab.html), and while I may be interpreting it wrongly I think the [xlsxwriter documentation on working with macros](https://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/working_with_macros.html#macros) allows it to add macro files from an existing workbook to a new one. Perhaps you could create a vba bin and use excelwriter to add it to the worksheet?